# PHP removing an array element and inserting it into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays which are in the same form as below; for examples sake, lets call them $array1 and $array2

```
Array (
    [Element1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [morethings] => 145
            [somemore] => namehere
        )
    [Element2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [morethings] => 145
            [somemore] => namehere
        )
    [Element3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [morethings] => 145
            [somemore] => namehere
        )
)
```

What I need to do is take Element2 from the first array and then insert it into array2 as NewElement2

I have the following below but it keeps returning nothing at all in array2

```
$searchArray = array_search('Element2', $array1);
array_splice($array2, $searchArray, 1, array('NewElement2'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your over thinking it `$array2['Element2']=$array1['Element2'];`

Comment: @rtfm wont that kill all the rest of the elements in the array?

Comment: test it and find out

Comment: @rtfm That did indeed work ... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for assign the value  you can  simply

```
 $array2['Element2'] = $array1['Element2'];
```

(this append or repalce the entry for Elemet2 in $array2)

and for remove the value

```
 unset($array1['Element2']);
```